# Elasticsearch (PHP) multiple range filters issue

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am pretty new to Elasticsearch, so apologies if this is is an obvious question!

I am using the PHP library and trying to do a pretty straightforward query across an index. The only thing I wanted to do was perform a filter against two dates (visible_from and visible_to) which I have set to date types when creating the mapping.

I am building up a filtered query in the code, which ends up looking like this:

```
array (
  'index' => 'site',
  'from' => 0,
  'size' => 10,
  'body' => 
  array (
    'query' => 
    array (
      'filtered' => 
      array (
        'filter' => 
        array (
          'and' => 
          array (
            'range' => 
            array (
              'visible_from' => 
              array (
                'lt' => '2014-06-09 09:06:47',
              ),
              'visible_to' => 
              array (
                'gt' => '2014-06-09 09:06:47',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        'query' => 
        array (
          'match' => 
          array (
            '_all' => 'example',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

This results in a BadRequest400Exception being thrown - in the content of the exception I can see that Elasticssearch is saying

```
QueryParsingException[[site] [and] filter does not support [lt]]
```

If I remove the AND filter and just perform the range filter against one of the dates, then it works perfectly, I am just unable to get it working with the AND filter

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a try with below query, Try with different less than and greater than date.

```
array
(
    "query" => array
    (
    "filtered" => array
    (
        "query" => array
        (
            "match" => array(
                 '_all' => 'example',
                ),
             ),

            "filter" => array
            (
                "and" => array
                (
                    "filters" => array
                    (
                        "0" => array
                        (
                            "range" => array
                            (
                                "ID" => array
                                (
                                "gt" => '2014-06-09 09:06:47',
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                        "1" => array
                        (
                            "range" => array
                            (
                                "ID" => array
                                (
                                    "lt" => '2014-06-09 09:06:47',
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
)
```

Comment: That was very helpful, thanks. I had to substitute 'ID' for my attributes, but the use of the filters array worked. Many thanks!

Comment: Glad to know it works for you :) You can use `visible_to` and `visible_from` as well it will work. `ID` is a field name in my example.