# Elasticsearch more than one range

Tags: php, elasticsearch, range

I work with the PHP client and try to add ranges to my query.  The ranges are working, but only the last one.

How can I use both ranges?

```
Array ( 
[index] => myindex 
[size] => 75 
[sort] => Array ( 
[0] => DATE:desc 
    ) 
[body] => Array ( 
    [query] => Array ( 
        [filtered] => Array ( 
        [query] => Array (
             [match] => Array ( 
                [_all] => Array ( 
                    [query] => My Query
                    [operator] => and 
                    [fuzziness] => 0.8 ) ) ) 
        [filter] => Array ( 
            [range] => Array ( 
                [DATE] => Array ( 
                    [format] => MM/dd/yyyy||yyyy 
                    [gte] => 01/01/2015 
                    [lt] => 12/31/2016 ) 
                [ART] => Array ( 
                    [gte] => 3 
                    [lt] => 4 ) ) ) ) ) ) )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this link : [multiple range filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116876/elasticsearch-php-multiple-range-filters-issue) or this : [multiple range filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439100/elastic-search-multiple-ranges-in-php)

generally search for the phrase "elasticsearch multiple range"